# Shell script to copy bluetoothctl attribute value to file

Tags: bash, shell, bluetooth

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set prompt "#"
send "script acid12.txt\r"
sleep 2
set address 34:85:18:6a:52:52
spawn bluetoothctl
expect -re $prompt
send "connect $address\r"
expect "Connection successful"
sleep 0.2
send "menu gatt\r"
sleep 1
send "select-attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_85_18_6A_52_52/service002e/char0032\r"
sleep 2
send "notify on\r" 
sleep 10
send "exit\r"
sleep 1
send "exit\r"
send "quit\r"
expect eof
```

this is my code and it works to get this data::

```
[CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_85_18_6A_52_52/service002e/char0032 Value:
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 32 01 07 e0 14 61 00 *70* 00 00  ......2....a.p..
  00 05 1d 4c 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff  ...L............
  00 01
```

i would really like to be able to pull the value from terminal and save it to a .txt file

the value i really only need is 70 that i made bold above..

i tried adding script acid12.txt but it doesnt make a file

to clarify i would like to save the notify output from the bluetoothctl output to a file

heres notify on dump

```
mike@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ ./script2.sh
spawn bluetoothctl
[4GRDH]# connect 34:85:18:6a:52:52
Attempting to connect to 34:85:18:6a:52:52
Agent registered
Connection successful
[4GRDH]# menu gatt
Menu gatt:
Available commands:
-------------------
list-attributes [dev/local]                       List attributes
select-attribute <attribute/UUID>                 Select attribute
attribute-info [attribute/UUID]                   Select attribute
read [offset]                                     Read attribute value
write <data=xx xx ...> [offset] [type]            Write attribute value
acquire-write                                     Acquire Write file descriptor
release-write                                     Release Write file descriptor
acquire-notify                                    Acquire Notify file descriptor
release-notify                                    Release Notify file descriptor
notify <on/off>                                   Notify attribute value
clone [dev/attribute/UUID]                        Clone a device or attribute
register-application [UUID ...]                   Register profile to connect
unregister-application                            Unregister profile
register-service <UUID> [handle]                  Register application service.
unregister-service <UUID/object>                  Unregister application service
register-includes <UUID> [handle]                 Register as Included service in.
unregister-includes <Service-UUID><Inc-UUID>      Unregister Included service.
register-characteristic <UUID> <Flags=read,write,notify...> [handle] Register application characteristic
unregister-characteristic <UUID/object>           Unregister application characteristic
register-descriptor <UUID> <Flags=read,write...> [handle] Register application descriptor
unregister-descriptor <UUID/object>               Unregister application descriptor
back                                              Return to main menu
version                                           Display version
quit                                              Quit program
exit                                              Quit program
help                                              Display help about this program
export                                            Print environment variables
[4GRDH]# select-attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_85_18_6A_52_52/service002e/char0032
[4GRDH:/service002e/char0032]# notify on
[CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_85_18_6A_52_52/service002e/char0032 Notifying: yes
Notify started
[CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_85_18_6A_52_52/service002e/char0032 Value:
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 32 01 07 e4 14 62 00 70 00 00  ......2....b.p..
  00 05 1d 4c 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff  ...L............
  00 01                                            ..              
[CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_85_18_6A_52_52/service002e/char0032 Value:
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 32 01 07 e2 14 64 00 70 00 00  ......2....d.p..
  00 05 1d 4c 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff  ...L............
  00 01                                            ..              
[CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_85_18_6A_52_52/service002e/char0032 Value:
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 32 01 07 e2 14 60 00 70 00 00  ......2....`.p..
  00 05 1d 4c 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff  ...L............
  00 01                                            ..              
[CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_85_18_6A_52_52/service002e/char0032 Value:
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 32 01 07 e2 14 62 00 70 00 00  ......2....b.p..
  00 05 1d 4c 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff  ...L............
  00 01                                            ..              
[CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_85_18_6A_52_52/service002e/char0032 Value:
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 32 01 07 e2 14 60 00 70 00 00  ......2....`.p..
  00 05 1d 4c 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff  ...L............
  00 01                                            ..              
[CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_85_18_6A_52_52/service002e/char0032 Value:
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 32 01 07 e1 14 63 00 70 00 00  ......2....c.p..
  00 05 1d 4c 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff  ...L............
  00 01                                            ..              
[CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_85_18_6A_52_52/service002e/char0032 Value:
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 32 01 07 e2 14 65 00 70 00 00  ......2....e.p..
  00 05 1d 4c 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff  ...L............
  00 01                                            ..              
[CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_85_18_6A_52_52/service002e/char0032 Value:
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 32 01 07 e2 14 64 00 70 00 00  ......2....d.p..
  00 05 1d 4c 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff  ...L............
  00 01                                            ..              
[CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_85_18_6A_52_52/service002e/char0032 Value:
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 32 01 07 e2 14 67 00 70 00 00  ......2....g.p..
  00 05 1d 4c 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff  ...L............
  00 01                                            ..              
[CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_85_18_6A_52_52/service002e/char0032 Value:
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 32 01 07 e0 14 61 00 70 00 00  ......2....a.p..
  00 05 1d 4c 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff  ...L............
  00 01                                            ..              
[4GRDH:/service002e/char0032]# exit
```

Comment: Just redirect the output of the script. `./script2.sh > filename`

Comment: can we assume you only need the 14th field of the second line (the 70 here)?

Comment: FYI: You don't need to do the `menu gatt` command to access the `gatt` commnads. You can prepend `gatt.` to the gatt commands. e.g. `notify on` would become `gatt.notify on`. Also, bluetoothctl is not intended to be used to access the BlueZ functionality from scripts. There are a set of API's documented at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc. BlueZ have examples of using them at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test

Comment: @Nic3500 you are correct is there anyway to scrap that value?

Comment: @Barmar thank you that works for getting the entire output to a file. is there anyway to maybe get the one value or line?

Comment: would I be able to use the grep function to pull exact location of value i want?                ./script2.sh | grep Value: > alog.txt    ???

Comment: 1e is a constant fo the value being output and using that as the grep value allowe me to find this                                mike@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ ./script2.sh | grep 1e
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 04 01 07 16 14 14 00 65 00 00  .............e..
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 04 01 07 15 14 0f 00 65 00 00  .............e..
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 04 01 07 15 14 10 00 65 00 00  .............e..
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 04 01 07 15 14 14 00 65 00 00  .............e..
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 04 01 07 13 14 16 00 65 00 00  .............e..

Comment: ./script2.sh | grep 1e > logs.txt  works to get lines i needed...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is in file **data.txt**

```
[CHG] Attribute /org/bluez/hci0/dev_34_85_18_6A_52_52/service002e/char0032 Value:
  1e ff 02 09 03 1c 32 01 07 e0 14 61 00 *70* 00 00  ......2....a.p..
  00 05 1d 4c 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff 00 01 ff ff  ...L............
  00 01
```

You can use this command to extract the *70*

```
awk 'FNR == 2 { print $14 }' data.txt
```

- `FNR == 2`: second line of data.txt
- `{ print $14 }`: print the 14th element of that line, which is the *70* you are looking for.

Or you can do this if your data comes from some command:

```
some command | awk 'FNR == 2 { print $14 }'
```

Comment: thank you Nic , i fiddled with the code a bit and have it working to pull that exact value! much appreciated